# Spring MVC controller test fails with empty body

Tags: spring-mvc-test

I am writing a small REST API with spring boot and trying to write the MVC test.
Unfortunately the MVC tests fails as I get the empty response from the controller.

**Controller class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getMessage(){
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = null;
        try {
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity("Hello from: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

**MVC test method:**

```
public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/test")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello from:")));
}
```

The problem is that I get `content()` always empty.
I tried to print the response as below

```
MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/test")).andReturn();
String res = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

which clearly says `res` is empty.
I have also a mockito test which works perfectly with proper response.
**Mockito test:**

```
@Test
public void greetingShouldReturnMessageFromService() throws Exception {
    when(service.getMessage()).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok("Hello from:"));
}
```

**Output for MVC test:**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /test
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.test.rest.controller.TestController$MockitoMock$625340695
           Method = com.test.rest.controller.TestController$MockitoMock$625340695#getMessage()

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /test
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.test.rest.controller.TestController$MockitoMock$625340695
           Method = com.test.rest.controller.TestController$MockitoMock$625340695#getMessage()

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /test
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.test.rest.controller.TestController$MockitoMock$625340695
           Method = com.test.rest.controller.TestController$MockitoMock$625340695#getMessage()

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


java.lang.AssertionError: Response content
Expected: a string containing "Hello from:"
     but: was ""
Expected :a string containing "Hello from:"
Actual   :""
<Click to see difference>


    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:18)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers.lambda$string$3(ContentResultMatchers.java:129)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at com.test.rest.TestControllerMockTest.shouldReturnDefaultMessage(TestControllerMockTest.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but after modifying the method as below it worked.

```
@Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        when(service.getMessage()).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok("Hello from:")); // Added this line
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/test")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello from:")));
    }
```

In the above method, I added `when(service.getMessage()).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok("Hello from:"));` line and the test passed.

**Ref**: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/
At the end of this page stated that:

> We use @MockBean to create and inject a mock for the GreetingService
> (if you do not do so, the application context cannot start), and we
> set its expectations using Mockito

.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried @RequestMapping at the method level?

Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello") //Changed here
public ResponseEntity getMessage(){
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = null;
    try {
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity("Hello from: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseEntity;
}
```

You will need to change the url that you are now accessing to "/test/hello".

Comment: This shouldn't have any effect on the issue I think

Comment: Checked as suggested... still the same issue